# HTML Mobile Font Size in Button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a web page that is also mobile friendly. I tested it on my phone and in Chrome's device mode. The majority of the text on the screen displayed large enough to easily read without needing to zoom. I found that my buttons and inline-block divs had much smaller text. I tried messing around with css to fix it but I couldn't figure out why those were smaller than any other text.

As I was trying to create a small demo to post here, I found another rather strange thing that was happening. If the body held more than 240 characters (text that is displayed), the text would display large, as desired, but if I had less than 241 characters, the text would be as small as the text on the buttons. I saw this happen in Chrome's device mode, using a number of devices, such as the Google Nexus 5. What would cause this to happen?

Anyways, this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me">
    <p>1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 123456</p>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">small text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't get this to show my issue in a JSFiddle, so to see it you can just save that as an html page and run it in Chrome, using its device mode. You should see that the numbers in the `p` tag display large enough to read, while the text on the button and the `div` are quite small. If you get rid of a character in the `p` its text should become just as small as the other text on the page.

What I want is to have the larger text everywhere, so it is easily readable on a mobile device, while not becoming extra large when viewing it on a desktop. How can I fix this?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ...`

Comment: took one look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add 
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>` in your head section. Also take in consideration that the font family and font size in a p-tag will be different from the ones in a button-tag.

Comment: That works for what I specified, but in addition to the sample html, I have an image that has a width and height specified in pixels, and this causes that image to  become much larger than I would like. Do you know of a way to only adjust the font size? Also, I am aware that those fonts will be different, and I have css to fix the minor differences.

Comment: well it's normal for that to happen, you said you wanted to make a mobile friendly website... that means you need to work with percentages when defining the width of an image and or using media queries to target specific window widths. So in a way mobile friendly  = defining the meta viewport, using percentages and using media queries.